# How to disable one prompt value in yii2 drop-down?

Tags: yii2

I've added a `prompt` to my `drop-down list` and I need to disable it, but somehow it doesn't work. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<?= $form->field($item, 'id')->dropDownList($items, [
   'prompt' => 'Choose your items',
   'promptOptions' => [
        'disabled' => true,
   ]
]); ?>
```

I've the information according to this, but found just post, which disables one `dropdown value`, but not prompt. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give you a work around, assuming the prompt option is first option(i think it is always), you can get id of that dropdown and make the first element disabled, like

```
$("#createconsultantprofileform-location option:first").prop('disabled', true)
```

In my case `createconsultantprofileform-location` is id of dropdown.
you need to add following code at the bottom of your view file with your dropdown id-

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
   $("#createconsultantprofileform-location:first").prop('disabled', true);
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Comment: I want to solve this in my way, I'm interested why the code doesn't work